# Mongo error: "$out stage requires a string argument, but found object (code: 14, codeName: TypeMismatch)"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write a Mongo aggregation using the [out operator as described in the docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#examples) This is the aggregation I'm writing:

```
db.mycollectionname.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $project: {}},
    { $out: {to: "projets", mode: "insertDocuments"}}
])
```

When I execute this I get the following error: **$out stage requires a string argument, but found object** - clear in and of itself but it goes against what the docs say. When I provide a string to the $out stage, I don't get the error but that's not what I want.

[image: executed from the terminal and from Studio3T.]

Mongo version: 3.6.9

(I have more logic under the $project pipeline stage which I removed for brevity, it doesn't have any impact).

Can someone help me understand why this differs from what the docs say? And how I can provide the arguments I want to pass to the out stage (an object containing "to" and "mode") as a string?

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the version specific documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

`$out` in MongoDB 3.6 and MongoDB 4.0 only require a single string. In MongoDB 4.2, `$out` can use a dictionary to set the `mode`.

Comment: Ah, good call. I didn't realise I could specify the version for the documentation. At least it makes sense now, even though the change is weird. Thanks very much Robert

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with your MongoDb version, you are using 3.6.9 but the document says:
MongoDB 4.2 adds a new syntax structure that implements expanded functionality and flexibility around merging aggregation pipeline results into a target collection, including support for sharded collections and output modes that preserve the existing collection data.

Just update your version and it will work. :)

Comment: MongoDB 4.2 is currently in development. MongoDB 4.0.6 is the current stable release.